# Why is server-config.wsdd not being created by the eclipse web services wizard?

Tags: apache-axis, tomcat7, eclipse-wtp, java2wsdl

I am using eclipse (Juno) to develop a web service for Tomcat 7 and Axis2. I have a java bean which I want to use to create the web service. The web service wizard seems to run ok but when the server starts I get this error message:

```
2012-11-08 13:31:20,059 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet (EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet.java:162) getServerEngineConfig 
    - Unable to find config file.  
    Creating new servlet engine config file: /WEB-INF/server-config.wsdd
```

I understand this to mean that **server-config.wsdd** is missing. How do I create this file? Why isn't it being generated automatically by the wizard?

**Update**
I recreated the project and the error message does not appear. I guess that I did something wrong. Perhaps Axis1 was being used as Andreas Veithen suggests below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an error message generated by Axis 1.x. If you are developing an Axis2 service, then you shouldn't attempt to deploy it on Axis 1.x.

Answer (score 0):

While generating java beans or wsdl, select start service option in webservices wizard then eclipse will create the `server-confid.wsdd` file for you. Hope this helps.